# RJDBC not loading as a library in Rapache

Tags: apache, r, rjava, rapache

So I need to get access to an MSSQL server in my Rapache program and when I try to load RJDBC as a library in my Rapache code I get server error. In the logs it looks like this:

```
    referer: http://10.21.8.145/
    Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
      call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
      error: unable to load shared object '/usr/lib/R/site-library/rJava/libs/rJava.so':
      libjvm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    Error: package/namespace load failed for 'rJava'
 Traceback:
    5: stop(gettextf("package/namespace load failed for %s", sQuote(package)), 
   call. = FALSE, domain = NA)
    4: library(rJava)
    3: eval.with.vis(expr, envir, enclos)
    2: eval.with.vis(ei, envir)
    1: source("/var/www/brew/optimization.R")
    [Fri Jun 15 13:57:29 2012] [error] [client 10.21.2.79] File does not exist:  /var/www/favicon.ico
```

Also I checked and rJava.so exists in that directory. Is it something with libjvm.so?

The thing is when I run this library(RJDBC) in just R it says this:

```
    Loading required package: DBI
    Loading required package: rJava
    Warning message:
    replacing previous import 'show' when loading 'rJava'
```

and then all my RJDBC code aftewards works fine. So is this a  problem with some Java configuration or is this a problem with rApache not being able to run the library because of the warning message?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is something with libjvm.so ;) rjava.so cannot find it!

Various linux distros (I presume you're running linux?) will start apache in a restricted environment thus limiting where the process can find shared libraries. I recommend looking through the shell scripts to see if this is happening.

I'd also investigate your dynamic linker run-time binding configuration, e.g., the /etc/ld.so.* files along with the ldconfig command.

Try running your code from your personal R session. If it doesn't run there, then you need to fix your java/rJava install first. If it does run there, then explore the topics I discussed above.

Oh, and I just remembered: rJava may source in some java specific environment variables, located in the rJava package installation. See if that's happening in your local session. If that's the case then you will most likely need these set when apache/rApache is run.

And as I mentioned above, if your distro is restricting apache's environment, then you'll have to shim those Java envirnment variables into that restriction process.

Cheers!

Jeff

Comment: Sorry I am really new to this. Can you go more in depth on how I would find these java environment variables and allow them in Apache

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and determined the cause to be that rApache was not setting the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable.  This needs to be set before an R environment is created for `rJava` (or any packages that depend on it) to initialize correctly (i.e. be able to find the path to `libjvm.so`).

You can check this with a simple test script:

```
setContentType('text/text')
cat(Sys.getenv()['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'], '\n')
DONE
```

Unfortunately, the simple fix using a `SetEnv` directive to Apache doesn't work.  Instead you need to do the following:

(Note the following was done on a 64-bit RHEL5 Server)

Add a file to `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` called `rApache_rJava.conf` with the following contents:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/server/
```

(the above line was the path to the parent directory of `libjvm.so` on my server)

As root:

```
$ /sbin/ldconfig
```

followed by restarting Apache

After Apache restarts you *should* be able to run R-scripts via rApache that depend on `rJava`, e.g. anything with lines like:

```
library(rJava)
```

The process above with additional reference links is also outlined here, on my blog:
http://oddhypothesis.blogspot.com/2012/06/making-rapache-load-rjava.html

### EDIT: Full Disclosure

The blog linked to above is my own

Comment: I edited your post just to add a quick disclosure that the blog you were linking to was your own. This is a decent answer and it's not inappropriate to post a link like this now and again when it's related and you have provided an extensive answer; you just need to include a disclosure that it's your site you are linking to, is all. :)

Comment: Here's the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion), where the requirement for disclosure is mentioned, just FYI.

Comment: Thanks.  I happened to refresh the page which seems to have removed your edit ... re-edited to add disclosure